# Función se ejecuta cuando no debería

Tags: javascript, php, funciones

Tengo un archivo capitulo.php con un botón de editar que al pulsarlo redirige a edit/capitulo.php.
Este botón es así:

```
<input type='button' value='Editar'
onclick=window.location.href='edit/capitulo.php?id=".$_GET["id"]."'
```

En edit/capitulo.php tengo el siguiente botón:

```
<input type=button value='Borrar capítulo' onclick=eliminar()>
```

Y la función eliminar() es así:

```
function eliminar() onclick{

if(confirm("¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar el capítulo?")) {

<?php
include "../conexion.php";
$miconexion->query("DELETE FROM capitulo WHERE id_capitulo LIKE '".$_GET["id"]."'");
?>

}


} 
</script>
```

El problema es que cuando pulso el botón editar de capitulo.php, cuando entro en edit/capitulo.php el capítulo ya se ha borrado de la base de datos, es decir, ya se ha ejecutado la función eliminar(). ¿A qué es debido?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include "../conexion.php";
$miconexion->query("DELETE FROM capitulo WHERE id_capitulo LIKE '".$_GET["id"]."'");
?>
```

Esto DEBE ir en otro archivo, el codigo php lo interpreta el servidor, cuando ya logras ver tu pagina el registro ya se ha eliminado. Segun la estructura que estas empleando deberia ser el archivo eliminar.php

Answer (score 1):

Acá estas mezclando las cosas!

PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta del lado del servidor, Javascript del lado del cliente.

"onclick" es un evento de Javascript.

Lo que podrías hacer es que al producirse el evento "onclick" se ejecute la función "eliminar" y pasarle el parámetro con la id del fichero a eliminar.

Algo así por ejemplo en edit/capitulo.php:

```
<input type=button value='Borrar capítulo' onclick=eliminar('1234')>

<script>
function eliminar(id) {
    //asigno el parametro pasado en la funcion a la variable "id"
    var id = id;
    // Muestro el cuadro de dialogo con el mensaje de confirmación
    if (confirm('¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar el capítulo?')) {
        // redirecciono al fichero php que ejecuta la consulta
        window.location.assign('eliminar.php?id=' + id);
    }
} 
</script>
```

Aquí arriba no hay PHP, aunque lógicamente lo ideal sería que pases ese parametro dinamicamente, así por ejemplo:

```
<input type=button value='Borrar capítulo' onclick=eliminar('<?php echo $id; ?>')>
```

Luego, en el fichero "eliminar.php":

```
<?php
include '../conexion.php';
$miconexion->query("DELETE FROM capitulo WHERE id_capitulo LIKE '".$_GET['id']."'");
echo 'Capitulo eliminado';
?>
```